# Output of pulp to numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pulp

I'm using pulp to solve a particular problem which has many variables, with a mixture of 1-D, 2-D and 3-D variables. When the solution is obtained, I would like to get these variables into k-dimensional numpy arrays.

Variables:

```
u = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("u", (ns, ns), 0, 1, "Integer")
v = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("v", (ns, ns), 0, 1, "Integer")
w = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("w", (ns, ns, ps), 0, 1, "Integer")
x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", (ns, ps), 0, 1, "Integer")
y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("y", (ms, ps), 0, 1, "Integer")
z = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("z", (ns), parameters.hold_duration_min,
                          parameters.hold_duration_max, "Continuous")

varnames = {"u": u, "v": v, "w": w, "x": x, "y": y, "z": z}
```

Input (after solving):

```
problem.variables()
```

Output:

```
[u_0_1, u_0_2, u_0_3, u_0_4, u_0_5, u_0_6, u_1_2, u_1_3, u_1_4, u_1_5, u_1_6, u_2_3, u_2_4, u_2_5, u_2_6, u_3_4, u_3_5, u_3_6, u_4_5, u_4_6, u_5_6, v_0_1, v_0_2, v_0_3, v_0_4, v_0_5, v_0_6, v_1_2, v_1_3, v_1_4, v_1_5, v_1_6, v_2_3, v_2_4, v_2_5, v_2_6, v_3_4, v_3_5, v_3_6, v_4_5, v_4_6, v_5_6, w_0_1_0, w_0_1_1, w_0_1_2, w_0_1_3, w_0_1_4, w_0_1_5, w_0_1_6, w_0_2_0, w_0_2_1, w_0_2_2, w_0_2_3, w_0_2_4, w_0_2_5, w_0_2_6, w_0_3_0, w_0_3_1, w_0_3_2, w_0_3_3, w_0_3_4, w_0_3_5, w_0_3_6, w_0_4_0, w_0_4_1, w_0_4_2, w_0_4_3, w_0_4_4, w_0_4_5, w_0_4_6, w_0_5_0, w_0_5_1, w_0_5_2, w_0_5_3, w_0_5_4, w_0_5_5, w_0_5_6, w_0_6_0, w_0_6_1, w_0_6_2, w_0_6_3, w_0_6_4, w_0_6_5, w_0_6_6, w_1_0_0, w_1_0_1, w_1_0_2, w_1_0_3, w_1_0_4, w_1_0_5, w_1_0_6, w_1_2_0, w_1_2_1, w_1_2_2, w_1_2_3, w_1_2_4, w_1_2_5, w_1_2_6, w_1_3_0, w_1_3_1, w_1_3_2, w_1_3_3, w_1_3_4, w_1_3_5, w_1_3_6, w_1_4_0, w_1_4_1, w_1_4_2, w_1_4_3, w_1_4_4, w_1_4_5, w_1_4_6, w_1_5_0, w_1_5_1, w_1_5_2, w_1_5_3, w_1_5_4, w_1_5_5, w_1_5_6, w_1_6_0, w_1_6_1, w_1_6_2, w_1_6_3, w_1_6_4, w_1_6_5, w_1_6_6, w_2_0_0, w_2_0_1, w_2_0_2, w_2_0_3, w_2_0_4, w_2_0_5, w_2_0_6, w_2_1_0, w_2_1_1, w_2_1_2, w_2_1_3, w_2_1_4, w_2_1_5, w_2_1_6, w_2_3_0, w_2_3_1, w_2_3_2, w_2_3_3, w_2_3_4, w_2_3_5, w_2_3_6, w_2_4_0, w_2_4_1, w_2_4_2, w_2_4_3, w_2_4_4, w_2_4_5, w_2_4_6, w_2_5_0, w_2_5_1, w_2_5_2, w_2_5_3, w_2_5_4, w_2_5_5, w_2_5_6, w_2_6_0, w_2_6_1, w_2_6_2, w_2_6_3, w_2_6_4, w_2_6_5, w_2_6_6, w_3_0_0, w_3_0_1, w_3_0_2, w_3_0_3, w_3_0_4, w_3_0_5, w_3_0_6, w_3_1_0, w_3_1_1, w_3_1_2, w_3_1_3, w_3_1_4, w_3_1_5, w_3_1_6, w_3_2_0, w_3_2_1, w_3_2_2, w_3_2_3, w_3_2_4, w_3_2_5, w_3_2_6, w_3_4_0, w_3_4_1, w_3_4_2, w_3_4_3, w_3_4_4, w_3_4_5, w_3_4_6, w_3_5_0, w_3_5_1, w_3_5_2, w_3_5_3, w_3_5_4, w_3_5_5, w_3_5_6, w_3_6_0, w_3_6_1, w_3_6_2, w_3_6_3, w_3_6_4, w_3_6_5, w_3_6_6, w_4_0_0, w_4_0_1, w_4_0_2, w_4_0_3, w_4_0_4, w_4_0_5, w_4_0_6, w_4_1_0, w_4_1_1, w_4_1_2, w_4_1_3, w_4_1_4, w_4_1_5, w_4_1_6, w_4_2_0, w_4_2_1, w_4_2_2, w_4_2_3, w_4_2_4, w_4_2_5, w_4_2_6, w_4_3_0, w_4_3_1, w_4_3_2, w_4_3_3, w_4_3_4, w_4_3_5, w_4_3_6, w_4_5_0, w_4_5_1, w_4_5_2, w_4_5_3, w_4_5_4, w_4_5_5, w_4_5_6, w_4_6_0, w_4_6_1, w_4_6_2, w_4_6_3, w_4_6_4, w_4_6_5, w_4_6_6, w_5_0_0, w_5_0_1, w_5_0_2, w_5_0_3, w_5_0_4, w_5_0_5, w_5_0_6, w_5_1_0, w_5_1_1, w_5_1_2, w_5_1_3, w_5_1_4, w_5_1_5, w_5_1_6, w_5_2_0, w_5_2_1, w_5_2_2, w_5_2_3, w_5_2_4, w_5_2_5, w_5_2_6, w_5_3_0, w_5_3_1, w_5_3_2, w_5_3_3, w_5_3_4, w_5_3_5, w_5_3_6, w_5_4_0, w_5_4_1, w_5_4_2, w_5_4_3, w_5_4_4, w_5_4_5, w_5_4_6, w_5_6_0, w_5_6_1, w_5_6_2, w_5_6_3, w_5_6_4, w_5_6_5, w_5_6_6, w_6_0_0, w_6_0_1, w_6_0_2, w_6_0_3, w_6_0_4, w_6_0_5, w_6_0_6, w_6_1_0, w_6_1_1, w_6_1_2, w_6_1_3, w_6_1_4, w_6_1_5, w_6_1_6, w_6_2_0, w_6_2_1, w_6_2_2, w_6_2_3, w_6_2_4, w_6_2_5, w_6_2_6, w_6_3_0, w_6_3_1, w_6_3_2, w_6_3_3, w_6_3_4, w_6_3_5, w_6_3_6, w_6_4_0, w_6_4_1, w_6_4_2, w_6_4_3, w_6_4_4, w_6_4_5, w_6_4_6, w_6_5_0, w_6_5_1, w_6_5_2, w_6_5_3, w_6_5_4, w_6_5_5, w_6_5_6, x_0_0, x_0_1, x_0_2, x_0_3, x_0_4, x_0_5, x_0_6, x_1_0, x_1_1, x_1_2, x_1_3, x_1_4, x_1_5, x_1_6, x_2_0, x_2_1, x_2_2, x_2_3, x_2_4, x_2_5, x_2_6, x_3_0, x_3_1, x_3_2, x_3_3, x_3_4, x_3_5, x_3_6, x_4_0, x_4_1, x_4_2, x_4_3, x_4_4, x_4_5, x_4_6, x_5_0, x_5_1, x_5_2, x_5_3, x_5_4, x_5_5, x_5_6, x_6_0, x_6_1, x_6_2, x_6_3, x_6_4, x_6_5, x_6_6, y_0_0, y_0_1, y_0_2, y_0_3, y_0_4, y_0_5, y_0_6, y_1_0, y_1_1, y_1_2, y_1_3, y_1_4, y_1_5, y_1_6, y_2_0, y_2_1, y_2_2, y_2_3, y_2_4, y_2_5, y_2_6, y_3_0, y_3_1, y_3_2, y_3_3, y_3_4, y_3_5, y_3_6, y_4_0, y_4_1, y_4_2, y_4_3, y_4_4, y_4_5, y_4_6, y_5_0, y_5_1, y_5_2, y_5_3, y_5_4, y_5_5, y_5_6, y_6_0, y_6_1, y_6_2, y_6_3, y_6_4, y_6_5, y_6_6, y_7_0, y_7_1, y_7_2, y_7_3, y_7_4, y_7_5, y_7_6, y_8_0, y_8_1, y_8_2, y_8_3, y_8_4, y_8_5, y_8_6, z_0, z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4, z_5, z_6]
```

What I'm looking to generate is a dictionary of numpy arrays to hold results, e.g. `results` such that, e.g.:

```
results["x"][1][4] == pulp.value(x[1][4])
type(results["x"]) == numpy.ndarray
results["z"][2] == pulp.value(z[2])
results(["w"][6][0][2]) == pulp.value(w[6][0][2])
```

I've tried some things using e.g. pandas, but can't get it to work for my mix of 1-D, 2-D and 3-D arrays:

```
results = {}
vfunc = numpy.vectorize(lambda i: pulp.value(i))
for k, v in varnames.items():
    try:
        results[k] = vfunc(pandas.DataFrame(v).values)
    except:
        pass
```

...the above works for the 2D variables, but not the 1-D or 3-D ones.

**EDIT: I've returned to this problem more recently on another project and have solved it far more neatly by defining a new class for multidimensional variables:**

```
import pulp
import numpy


class MultiDimensionalLpVariable:
    def __init__(self, name, dimensions, low_bound, up_bound, cat):
        self.name = name
        try:
            self.dimensions = (*dimensions,)
        except:
            self.dimensions = (dimensions,)
        self.low_bound = low_bound
        self.up_bound = up_bound
        assert cat in pulp.LpCategories, 'cat must be one of ("{}").'.format(
            '", "'.join(pulp.LpCategories)
        )
        self.cat = cat
        self.variables = self._build_variables_array()
        self.values = None

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.variables[index]

    def _build_variables_array(self):
        f = numpy.vectorize(self._define_variable)
        return numpy.fromfunction(f, self.dimensions, dtype="int")

    def _define_variable(self, *index):
        name = "_".join(map(str, (self.name, *index)))
        return pulp.LpVariable(name, self.low_bound, self.up_bound, self.cat)

    def evaluate(self):
        f = numpy.vectorize(lambda i: pulp.value(i))
        self.values = f(self.variables)
```

I can now define a new variable as follows:

```
x = MultiDimensionalLpVariable("x",(10,20), 0, 1, "Binary")
```

Individual variables can be accessed by doing e.g.

```
>>> x[1,2]
x_1_2
```

or:

```
>>> x[1][2]
x_1_2
```

This allows constraints to be implemented in a clear syntax, e.g. the equation:

[image]

can be written as:

```
for n in range(N):
        problem += sum([x[n][p] for p in range(P)]) == 1
```

This approach is generalizable to any number of dimensions.

Once the problem has been solved, the values of the variables can be obtained

```
>>> x.evaluate()
>>> x.values
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

Individual variable values can be accessed by doing e.g.

```
>>> x.values[1,2]
1.0
```

or:

```
>>> x.values[1][2]
1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: Ignore this solution - found a much neater method, see original problem statement.**

I solved the problem as follows in the end.

The class  structure may be useful to others using multidimensional variables.

The key was in defining functions to translate between a numpy array and a dict of dicts of dicts of... etc.

This then allows evaluation, upon solution, to be carried out in a vectorized manner on the array, giving a numpy array of solution values which is useful for further processing.

It also allows a relatively clean syntax for defining multidimensional LP constraints.

```
import numpy as np
import pulp

class Variable_Matrix:

    def __init__(self, name, dimensions, low_bound, up_bound, cat):
        self.name = name
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        self.low_bound = low_bound
        self.up_bound = up_bound
        self.cat = cat
        self.variable_objects = unflatten_variable(
                pulp.LpVariable.dicts(self.name,
                                      tuple([range(i) for i in dimensions]),
                                      self.low_bound, self.up_bound, self.cat),
                                      self.dimensions)
        self.values = np.empty(self.dimensions)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.variable_objects(index)

    def evaluate(self):
        vectorized_evaluation = np.vectorize(lambda i: pulp.value(i))
        self.values = vectorized_evaluation(self.variable_objects)

# Generator for accessing components of a variable, returning the component and
# its position
def variable_iterator_loc(variable, dimensions):
    index = [0]* len(dimensions)
    depth = 0
    yield from _variable_iterator_loc(variable, dimensions, index, depth)


# Recursive function called by variable_iter_loc
def _variable_iterator_loc(variable, dimensions, index, depth):
    depth += 1
    if len(dimensions) == 1:
        for i in range(dimensions[0]):
            index[depth - 1] = i
            yield variable[i], tuple(index)
    else:
        for i in range(dimensions[0]):
            index[depth - 1] = i
            yield from _variable_iterator_loc(variable[i], dimensions[1:],
                                              index, depth)


# create a k-dimensional numpy array of variable objects, given the variable
# as a (dict of dict of ... of dicts) of depth k.
def unflatten_variable(variable, dimensions):
    unflattened = np.empty(dimensions, object)
    variter = variable_iterator_loc(variable, dimensions)
    for i in range(np.prod(dimensions)):
        varobject, position = next(variter)
        unflattened[position] = varobject
    return unflattened
```

This allows a clean syntax for defining multidimensional variables, e.g.:

```
x = Variable_Matrix("x", (N, N, P), 0, 1, "Integer")
y = Variable_Matrix("y", (N, P), 0, 1, "Integer")
z = Variable_Matrix("z", (N,), c_min, c_max, "Continuous")
```

Which in turn allows for clean syntax in defining multidimensional constraints, e.g.:

```
problem = pulp.LpProblem("My Problem", pulp.LpMinimize)

for n in range(N):
    problem += sum([y[n][p] for p in range(P)]) == 1
```

Results can be generated as follows (once LP has been solved):

```
y.evaluate()
```

And can be accessed e.g. as follows:

```
y.values[2,3]
```

The above requires a good deal of additional functions and complexity, but with the end goal of having very clean syntax for constructing the LP equations and for retrieving results and abstracts well to variables with many dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

initially your result, in Pulp, are stored in a dictionary but aren't sorted for an array. So you need to extract them at the right place in your ndarray. In addition in my case, among the variables there's slack variables I don't care about, so I need to extract the meaning full one first.

```
#storing Optimisation result (alpha & beta) in a new dictionary
varDic = {}
for v in prob.variables():
    if v.name[:5] == 'alpha' or v.name == 'b':
        varDic[v.name] = v.varValue

#passing solution (alpha, beta) to proper ndarray
b = varDic['b']
del varDic['b'] #remove beta from dictionary so only alpha is left

x = np.zeros(N)
#storing the value of alpha_i in x(i)
for key in varDic:
    x[int(key[6:])] = varDic[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question now, but for my own benefit there is a better (or at least another) way to do this. It's actually to use the objects to which you assigned the variable dictionaries:

`u = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("u", (ns, ns), 0, 1, "Integer")
v = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("v", (ns, ns), 0, 1, "Integer")
w = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("w", (ns, ns, ps), 0, 1, "Integer")
x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", (ns, ps), 0, 1, "Integer")
y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("y", (ms, ps), 0, 1, "Integer")
z = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("z", (ns), parameters.hold_duration_min,
                          parameters.hold_duration_max, "Continuous")`

After you have solved the problem, you can get arrays of the solutions by:

`u_soln = np.array([[u[i][j].varValue for i in ns] for j in ns])`

Etc.

Comment: Thanks. This works well for short problems, but the method for accesing solutions isn't generalizable to any number of dimensions.